# Replicating Semantic Analysis Model in Demo

Tags: pytorch, semantic-analysis, allennlp

Good day, I am a student that is interested in NLP. I have come across the demo on  [AllenNLP's homepage](https://demo.allennlp.org/sentiment-analysis), which stated that:

> The model is a simple LSTM using GloVe embeddings that is trained on the binary classification setting of the Stanford Sentiment Treebank. It achieves about 87% accuracy on the test set.

Is there any reference to the sample code or any tutorial that I can follow to replicate this result, so that I can learn more about this subject? I am trying to obtain a Regression Output (Instead of classification).

I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AllenAI provides all code for examples and lib opensource on Git, including AllenNLP.

I found exactly how the example was run here: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/allennlp/tests/data/dataset_readers/stanford_sentiment_tree_bank_test.py

However, to make it a Regression task, you'll have to tweak directly on Pytorch, which is the underlying technology for AllenNLP.